# Connection to Oracle with Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sockets, jboss, icefaces-1.8

My web application (Java jsf [icefaces](http://www.icesoft.org/) - jboss), is connected to Oracle using [hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/). It works correctly, but if there is period of user inactivity(some hours), when an user tries to make a query, occurs this error:
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

The application is utilized by 3/4 users, so there is a very small number of opened connections.
I can solve the problem rebooting jboss server.

Below is shown the hibernate.cfg.xml utilized by the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration> 
    <session-factory> 
        <!-- <property name="connection.datasource">portaleClientiOracleDS</property> -->       
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>   
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>   
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Alfre$cost12</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.216.109:1521:ALFHIST</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">ALFRESCOST</property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.default_catalog">ALFRESCOST</property>-->
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.default_schema">ALFRESCOST</property>-->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property> 
        <property name="use_outer_join">true</property>   
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>  

       <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property> <!-- seconds -->
        <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
        <property name="c3p0.min_size">10</property>
        <property name="c3p0.timeout">100</property> 
        <property name="c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</property>
        <property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>

        <mapping resource="it/pillar/accenture/portaleclienti/businesslayer/clienti/dao/hibernate/mappings/StoricoPillar.hbm.xml"/>    

    </session-factory>    
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I've tried to increase c3p0 values, but the problem remains intact. Any suggestions are appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're probably no using c3p0. [The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-hibernatejdbc) says:

> Hibernate will use its org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
>   for connection pooling if you set hibernate.c3p0.* properties. If you
>   would like to use Proxool, refer to the packaged hibernate.properties
>   and the Hibernate web site for more information.
>
> The following is an example hibernate.properties file for c3p0:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase
hibernate.connection.username = myuser
hibernate.connection.password = secret
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

So the properties should be `hibernate.c3p0.xxx` and not `c3p0.xxx`.

Comment: Thank for your post. Unfortunately, it hasn't solved the problem... I have noticed that , when an user try to make a query, the first error occurs is :
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Read timed out

Then, if a user make another query, the error is
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

i'm going crazy....